# The [high-resolution] has been downscaled

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

[high-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/high-resolution) has 163 questions with no tag wiki usage guidance. The concept is ambiguous as resolution alone could refer to *quality* of optics, images, rendering, sound or really any digital compression of an analog datum. Resolution can also refer to *precision*, frequency and other temporal or time-series concepts.

When [high-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/high-resolution) is added to posts it does not always mean the same thing. We can loosely break the intended meanings into these categories: *Visual quality; data precision/accuracy; device display resolution.* But each of those is still quite broad and will need further meta to describe the specific programming conceptual domain the tag refers to.

Given the wide range of domains, this tag cannot be used on its own to tag a post and is therefore a meta-tag at best, but in many questions it actually distracts from the real underlying issue raised in the OP.

- A user could not claim to be an *expert* of [high-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/high-resolution) on its own, they might claim to be an expert in high-res [image-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) or in dealing with high DPI screen resolutions in reactive [layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layout), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) or perhaps [flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox). However the [image-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) skills  and knowledge do not transfer to HTML layout management concepts at all.
- I can find only a single user who has answered more than one [high-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/high-resolution) post, both of those are highly specific to `imageWithContentsOfFile` in to iOS:

  - Q: How to activate @2x high res graphics for retina display?

    - A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742865/1690217
  - Q: How to get [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:] and High Res Images working -

    - A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4446640/1690217

> There are **zero** posts tagged exclusively with [high-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/high-resolution).

These are some example groupings of the associated posts:

- Machine learning and analytics of images

  - https://stackoverflow.com/q/70821768/1690217
- Processing large file (size related) issues

  - [How to process high resolution photo in Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25793041/1690217)
- UI layouts / responsive design

  - [Detecting HiDPI Windows Phone 8 Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14654425/1690217)
  - [Website on high resolution screen is too small](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26024838/1690217)
- Timers and interval processing

  - [High resolution timer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24839105/1690217)
  - [How to create a high resolution timer in Linux to measure program performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6749621/1690217)
- Application or API specific

  - [Highest resolution for Google / Bing map API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29764266/1690217)
  - [Why is my audio AVCaptureConnection not active for highest-resolution formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29241365/1690217)
  - https://stackoverflow.com/q/52634479/1690217
- Performance and application behaviours on high-DPI monitors

  - https://stackoverflow.com/q/44516794/1690217
  - [SWF files loads very slow in high resolution screens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26214059/1690217)

There are other related tags that are potential synonym candidates, but they do not reduce the ambiguity of this concept:[highdpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highdpi), [hidpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidpi), [dpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dpi), [resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resolution) [precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/precision)

IMO most of the topics discussed with [high-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/high-resolution) are *on topic*, but the tag itself has too many meanings when used in conjunction with more appropriate tags. In many cases the purpose of tag could be replaced with a meaningful edit to the title of the post.

Should we burninate this tag?

Comment: Just adding some context, looks like the oldest visible question having this tag is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/182554/2821954) posted in 2008 when SO was still in its infancy and [meta tags have not yet been declared a problem](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags) ... and this tag indeed smells like a meta tag.

Comment: In hardware-related programming there's also numerous of other cases. You'll have hardware named "high resolution timer", "high resolution ADC" etc.

Answer (score 51):

This tag is ambiguous and should be removed.

[What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination)

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It does not. Mostly it seems to just be added to the tag list as an adjective, as if giving emphasis to something through the use of tags. It is very ambiguous.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

No. It is too broad and vague to be called a topic. What exactly that qualifies as "high" resolution is very context-specific.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No.

Answer (score 4):

[high-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/high-resolution) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Progress:

The [high-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/high-resolution) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=high-resolution),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhigh-resolution%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhigh-resolution%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhigh-resolution%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhigh-resolution%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of burnination](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=415709)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [high-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/high-resolution) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [high-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/high-resolution) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [high-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/high-resolution) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.